# c++ asm move pointer to register = access violation error

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm using asm insert to clear bitmap, that was created like this:

```
CreateDIBSection(m_dc, &bmpinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&m_bmp_data, NULL, NULL);
```

asm insert (**C++**)

```
int c = RGB32(color.r, color.g, color.b);

int length = m_width * m_height;

__asm
{
    mov edi, m_bmp_data
    mov ecx, length
    mov eax, c
    rep stosd
}
```

this code throws access violation error. But if i do it like this - all ok:

```
BYTE* dest = m_bmp_data;
__asm
{
    mov edi, dest
...
```

What is difference between this peaces?

**UPDATED:**
with "mov edi, m_bmp_data" it translates in "mov edi, 10h". Why 10h? With "mov edi, dest" it translates in "mov edi, dword ptr [dest]". really, i don't find how to use memset with integer values, so i just use inline asm

Comment: What's the type of `m_bmp_data` in the first section?

Comment: it's unsigned char* (or BYTE*)

Comment: Check the generated assembly code. By the way, do you have a reason to reinvent `memset`? Your compiler usually does a good enough job optimizing that.

Comment: with "mov edi, m_bmp_data" it translates in "mov edi, 10h". Why 10h? With "mov edi, dest" it translates in "mov edi, dword ptr [dest]". really, i don't find how to use memset with integer values, so i just use inline asm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mov edi, m_bmp_data
```

That will only work correctly when m_bmp_data is a local or global variable.  The name strongly suggest it is not, in all likelihood is a member of a C++ class.  Which requires dereferencing the *this* pointer, like this:

```
    __asm {
        mov eax, this;
        mov edi, [eax + m_bmp_data];
        // etc..
    }
```

Actually writing this code doesn't make sense, you might as well use the workaround you found, the compiler never gets this wrong.